# Android - AsyncTask not refreshing Fragment RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm kind new on Android and I have followed this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) to create the initial structure of my app, with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`.

Every page is a Fragment (which I don't know if it's the right way), but it's setted like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       adapter.addFragment(new CarListFragment());
       adapter.addFragment(new ProductsFragment());
       adapter.addFragment(new UserFragment());
       this.baseViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

}
```

**CarListFragment**:

```
public class CarListFragment extends Fragment implements ICarListTask {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View carListFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carlist_fragment, parent, false);
        carList = (RecyclerView) carListFragment.findViewById(R.id.car_list);

    new CarListTask(this.getContext(), this).execute();

    return carListFragment;
}

@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(ArrayList<Car> result) {

    if (carList != null) {

        if (result == null) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            adapter = new CarAdapter(this.getContext(), result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

*There is no relevant code at `CarListTask` (just getting some data from an web API).

The issue is that `CarAdapter.onCreateViewHolder` and `CarAdapter.onBindViewHolder` are never invoked and consequently the RecyclerView is not populated.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

CarList Implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/car_list"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:dividerHeight="10sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CarListTask:**

```
public class CarListTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ArrayList<Car>> {

private Context context;
private ICarListTask callback;

public CarListTask (Context context, Fragment fragment) {
    this.context = context;
    this.callback = (ICarListTask) fragment;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Car> doInBackground(Object... params) {

    ...// methods to connect to web API
    try {

        //data is the result from WEB API, which is OK
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray(data);
        Type collectionType =  new TypeToken<ArrayList<Car>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), collectionType);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    this.callback.onLoadingComplete(result);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show us how `carList` is defined and what the `CarListTask` code looks like.

Comment: You need to set the adapter also

Comment: It seems recyclerview doesn't have a layout manager set, set a layout manager : cartList.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(this) ); Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @AlokOmkar It did the trick! Please answer it so I can give you credits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add linear layout manager to the recyclerview :

```
cartList.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

A RecyclerView needs to have a layout manager and an adapter to be instantiated. A layout manager positions item views inside a RecyclerView and determines when to reuse item views that are no longer visible to the user.

RecyclerView provides these built-in layout managers:

1. LinearLayoutManager shows items in a vertical or horizontal
   scrolling list.
2. GridLayoutManager shows items in a grid.
3. StaggeredGridLayoutManager shows items in a staggered grid.

Guide on Recyclerview usage :

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new adapter each time, but you don't set it

```
adapter = new CarAdapter(this.getContext(), result);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

NotifyDataSetChanged() has no use as it is a new adapter, which is not set to any recycler.

```
adapter = new CarAdapter(this.getContext(), result);
carList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or create a method in your adapter which takes the result and then call NotifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Setting the adapter to `carList` was my first shot. Then I got confused and lost some code. But it didn't work as well.

Comment: I also thought it would, but  I have no clue why it doesn't.